# How to write the code of this character?

Tags: symbols

I am writing my B.Sc. thesis. But, I have no idea how to write the following character:[image: image of symbol]

I was trying by `$\mathcal{O}$`, but this is not the same I want.

Answer (score 19):

The request symbol is into `calrsfs` package. Here there is a screenshot of the symbol.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{calrsfs}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal{O}_X$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 19):

This is an addendum to Sebastiano's answer, who correctly identified the font. However, I personally always load it with the `mathrsfs` package since that way `\mathcal` retains its original definition, and you can get the "strange" O with `\mathscr{O}`. In particular you also get a nice Lagrange L via `\mathscr{L}` without losing the ability to produce a luminosity (say) L with `\mathcal{L}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\begin{document}
Using \verb|mathrsfs| to produce
\[\mathscr{O}_X\]
allows us to retain the original definition of \verb|\mathcal|,
\[ \mathscr{O} \quad\mbox{vs.}\quad \mathcal{O}\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad
 \mathscr{L} \quad\mbox{vs.}\quad \mathcal{L}\;.\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for to have put my name into your answer . Into my book I have different calligraphics font, `\mathscr{L}` and `\mathcal{L}`. My best regards and best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

As an addendum, I would recommend loading extra math alphabets through `mathalpha`, which provides a consistent interface and scaling—if you are using legacy 8-bit fonts.  If you can use the modern toolchain with `unicode-math`, even better. This gives you a consistent interface to scale the alphabets and load them as either `\mathscr` or `\mathcal`.

[The documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf) for `mathalpha` also comes with specimens of dozens of math alphabets for you to compare.  You might, for example, prefer a less heavily slanted version, such as the one from `rsfso`.